# Using nginx + express on the request path problem

Tags: express, nginx

I have prepared a front-end, and the file is placed in
**/usr/local/var/www/front-end**

Then there is an express backend, a simple get example that returns a "yes" string, already started by express, with port 3000

-------- express --------

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('yes')
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('The : ' + port + 'are listen');
});
```

Now I want nginx to listen to the front-end, port 1155, and then set up a route, like an api, which will be proxied by nginx to port 3000

I did this test.

-------- nginx --------

```
server {
        listen 1155;
        server_name demo.com;
        location / {
            root /usr/local/var/www/front-end;
            index index.html;
        }
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
    }
```

However, when I test http://127.0.0.1:1155/api/ in postman, nginx only returns Cannot GET /api/

What am I doing wrong? I keep trying various combinations, but always fail, I can barely figure out the relationship between location and root, I hope this simple test will help me understand, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative 1:**
Remove the `/api` prefix from the url when forwarding it to the backend.

```
location /api/ {
  rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  …
}
```

**Alternative 2:**
Mount the backend server on `/api`

```js
app.get('/api/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('yes')
})
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, it really solved. But then I thought that there seems to be no problem to use both separately, I will try more, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An even cleaner way would be adding trailing `/` for the proxy_pass's value. NGINX will replace matched part (`/api/`) with provided URI `/`:

```
location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
  …
}
```

Thanks to that, `GET http://nginx/api` will be proxied to the `GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/`.

You can read more about this in the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).